# amazon mechanical turk external questions

Tags: mechanicalturk

Is there any policy or process in AMT that would prevent an ExternalQuestion from requesting that the worker download an application to perform their task on?  i.e. a desktop application rather than a web application?  The assignments and so on could be handled from the API as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is "yes, kinda".  While the policy itself doesn't explicitly prohibit it, the FAQ gives this as an example of a question that will be rejected.  I contacted the AMT team, and they confirmed verbally that it's prohibited.